# Как сделать REPLACE INTO в Laravel 5.X при помощи Eloquent ORM или Query Builder (только не чистым SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, composer

1. Есть в Laravel функционал для запросов REPLACE INTO?
2. Если нет какой пакет/библиотеку нужно доставить чтобы был?
3. Если нет пакета/библиотеки как можно самому расширить функционал нужными методами?

PS:Это решение пробовал https://gist.github.com/VinceG/0fb570925748ab35bc53f2a798cb517c не помогло.

Comment: REPLACE INTO это не стандарт SQL, и реализован не во всех РСУБД. ORM и билдеры как правило реализуют только универсальные методы (чтобы была возможность быстро переключиться с одного сервера БД на другой не переписывая код). Как подключали расширение, почему не помогло (в чем это проявилось)?

Comment: @NikitaRomannikov
Создал соответствующие файлы в соответствующих директориях и пробовал запустить, выбивало ошибку что нет метода "replace"

Comment: Вы как получали экземпляр билдера? Надо создавать новый явно указывая приведенный вами класс или прописывать в конфигах новых класс билдера вместо старого.

Comment: @NikitaRomannikov
Я пробовал делать запросы от App\Library\Database\Query\Builder но это как вы понимаете неправильно и не получилось, я догадывался что нужно что-то подключить или зарегистрировать но в описания модуля не было. Подскажите пожалуста как его подключить/зарегистрировать чтобы метод replace работал?

Comment: Напишите куда файл клали и приведите код как подключали

Comment: @NikitaRomannikov
Я сделал:
 1. Создал директрии App\Library\Database\Query.
 2. Создал файлы Builder.php в App\Library\Database\Query, Connection.php, MySqlGrammar.php, MySqlConnection.php в  App\Library\Database. С содержимым как указано в модуле.
Это все что я сделал. Запускал `DB::table('users')->replace(['user_id' => 4, 'user_name' => "aa", 'user_password' => 'test']);` класс `DB` импортировал с Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59362/discussion-between-arzek-and-nikita-romannikov).